# C# DateTime parsing "invalid format string"

Tags: c#, string, datetime, mono

I have an issue with `DateTime` parsing and format strings. The format string I supply appears to be fine, with every character and delimiter from the format string matching a digit or character from the date string. The error in particular reads **FormatException: Invalid format string**. I am using `Mono C#`, as shipped with the `Unity3D` game engine.

**Error:**

> "FormatException: Invalid format string"

**Code:**

```
string date_string = "3/9/2017 19:50";    
string date_format_string = "M/d/yyyy HH:mm";
print("string value: [" + date_string + "]");
print("format string: [" + date_format_string + "]");
DateTime new_dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date_string, date_format_string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Console output demonstrating the error:**
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Change your string format to "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"

Comment: I don't know anything about mono, but you should consider using `DateTime.TryParse()` so you do not throw an exception and you can handle the date string if it failed

Comment: @S.Petrosov I attempted that, and it didn't help, unfortunately. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yAQCrOblTcZU0waHZNWVpKVEU/view

Comment: @AustinYarger as I see on screen you tried "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm", but I advices "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"

Comment: @S.Petrosov My apologies. I tried that suggestion too. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yAQCrOblTcdUVyYnlyejQwcmM/view

Comment: I copied and pasted your code verbatim, and it works fine in .NET. It may be that Mono simply doesn't support the format string you want to use. There is nothing wrong with the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
string date_format_string = "M/d/yyyy HH:mm";
```

To the following correct format:

```
string date_format_string = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
```

Add leading Zeros to you date

```
string date_string = "3/9/2017 19:50";
```

like this

```
string date_string = "03/09/2017 19:50";
```

More about formatting in `DateTime.ParseExact` you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I attempted this, and it sadly did not work. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yAQCrOblTcdUVyYnlyejQwcmM/view

Comment: @AustinYarger have you tried to add leading Zeros to you string date_string = "3/9/2017 19:50";    like this string date_string = "03/09/2017 19:50"; ?

Comment: that works! I would really rather not force all of my dates into this format however. It's a shame how inflexible / fragile DateTime's parsing appears to be.

Comment: @AustinYarger I have updated my answer for the full content of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you,

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string dateWithFormat = date.ToLongDateString();
```

You can further modify the format of string. You can do this by `date.ToString("dd - MM - yyyy");` which would output something like `02 - 05 - 2017`

[Refer this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

I fixed it by ensuring that it was by default 1000-01-01 00:00:00.

This is because it's erroring when reading as "0000-00-00 00:00:00" because the lowest possible value is: 1000-01-01 00:00:00.